# Linq How to perform Subquery with max function that returns a primitive value such as an integer?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below query. :

```
List<MyItem> myList
    = randomEntity
           .GroupBy(x => new {
                x.Id,
                x.randomInnerEntity.Name,
                x.randomInnerEntity.Number
           })
           .Select(z => new MyItem
           {
               Id = z.Key.Id,
               Name = z.Key.Name,
               Totals = z.Count(),
               LatestObj = randomEntity.Where(x => x.Id == z.Key.Id)
                                       .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                                       .Select(gr => new {
                                            item1 = gr.Key,
                                            item2 = gr.Max(x => x.SomeInteger.Value)
                                       })
            })
            .OrderBy(z => z.Name)
            .ToList();
```

As you can see the inner subquery, that provides a dynamic object of LatestObj works but it provides an anonymous object.  I was wondering how to perform the same query but return a primitive type like integer.

***As requested

```
public class MyItem
{
    property Guid? Id { get; set; }
    property String Name { get; set; }
    property Int MaxValueTryingToGet { get; set; } //This is the field I would like to set with the integer max
    property Int Totals { get; set; }
    property dynamic LatestObj { get; set; }
    property randInner randomInnerEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you want one Max for all group or list of max for each group?

Comment: possibly you need just do `Select(gr=>gr.Max(x => x.SomeInteger.Value))`

Comment: It is a max per each MyItem Object being created.  The subquery is selecting off of multiple records per Entity record, it is a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: I tried the above first and it did not work.

Comment: Can you post the Type of `randomEntity`? That will make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LatestObj = randomEntity.Where(x => x.Id == z.Key.Id)
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                                   .Select(gr => new {
                                        item1 = gr.Key,
                                        item2 = gr.Max(x => x.SomeInteger.Value)
                                   })
```

Since you are just selecting items where the item id matches `z.Key.Id`, there does not seem to be much point grouping by id.

You can should be able to get the maximum value directly by using

```
LatestObj = randomEntity.Where(x => x.Id == z.Key.Id).Max(x -> x.SomeInteger.Value)
```

Comment: In this instance you are correct, I could just do what you have listed above.  My goal was to determine how to do this when a grouping has occurred as I have several other queries I am working on that are comparable to this but have far more group by items than the single one above.  This was the most simple query to show. +1 for a solution to this specific scenario.

Comment: I don't understand. If a grouping does occur, then your result may have multiple values (and presumably their keys) and hence it is impossible to assign it to a single integer.

Comment: I am now confused as the goal of the subquery is to return a single Max integer value.  In this instance it is returning an anonymous typed object.  My goal is to instead of returning an anon object is to return an integer associated with that max singular value returned.